# Get Device Certification Status Programmatically

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7165974?hl=en

As given in the above link, one can check your device's status in play store settings and make sure that your Android devices with Google apps work correctly. But I want to check the device certification status in my code. Is there a way for that?

Comment: You can check this https://source.android.com/compatibility/overview .

Comment: helped me confirm it's not supported through the API yet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think this is supported through API yet. You'll have to settle for [the manual checking through Google Play Settings](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7165974?hl=en) for now.

Comment: sadly i guess that's the conclusion! :(

Comment: How do Netflix doing that then?

Answer (score 0):

No need to test that now.
Google has rolled out a new feature in Play Console.
[Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455)